# Turtlebot navigation Made a map, but when using it with amcl_demo.launch, rviz doesn't completely load the map and amcl_demo node shows an error

Tags: ros, rviz, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[move_base-5] process has died [pid 5527, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/move_base/move_base cmd_vel:=navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel odom:=odom scan:=scan __name:=move_base __log:=/home/.ros/log/9136c460-3bff-11e5-8234-089e0125ee24/move_base-5.log].
log file: /home/.ros/log/9136c460-3bff-11e5-8234-089e0125ee24/move_base-5*.log
[amcl-2] process has died [pid 5371, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/amcl/amcl scan:=scan __name:=amcl __log:=/home/.ros/log/9136c460-3bff-11e5-8234-089e0125ee24/amcl-2.log].
log file: /home/.ros/log/9136c460-3bff-11e5-8234-089e0125ee24/amcl-2*.log
```

I am using indigo with gazebo 2.2.5

The amcl node would run fine if operated from another computer making this computer master in ros. All the navigation would work fine on the network. But when I try to do the complete thing including gazebo, rviz and amcl_demo on first computer the above error is prompted and the rviz 2dnavigation wouldn't work. Please help me out. The log files are empty.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215331/while-doing-the-turtlebot-navigation-tutorial-i-have-made-a-map-but-when-i-try-to-use-that-map-and-alunch-amcl_demo.launch-my-rviz-doesn%27t-completely-load-the-map.-and-the-amcl_demo-node-shows-the-follwoing-error./) by [Usman Arif](https://answers.ros.org/users/22287/usman-arif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2015-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-08-14**:
If multiple processes are quitting there are likely some other outputs from your system that would be useful for debugging this. Are there any other console outputs? Are you roslaunching with output to screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it can't get to the map?  I think you'd get a different error if it truly couldn't find the map, so if it all works when accessed from another computer, but not on the original one, it could be a permissions issue or some kind of config setting somewhere...

Are you setting the map location inside the launch file, or with a command-line argument when you run it?

---

Originally posted by [ElizabethA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26773/elizabetha/) with karma: 120 on 2016-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0